# LINQ 2 SQL query does not work with a function call

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am quite sure this question has already been asked several times and I do apolgize for asking it once again, but I made a few research and unfortunately I did not find my pleasure on the internet...

I have a IQueryable like this :

```
triggers = triggers.Where(t => GetIdFromName(t.Name) == filter.Id.ToString());
```

The function GetIdFromName get a part of the name to retrieve the Id :

```
public string GetIdProfiloFromName(string name)
        {
            return name.Substring(name.IndexOf(NameFirstSeparator)+1,name.IndexOf(NameSecondSeparator)-name.IndexOf(NameFirstSeparator)-1);
        }
```

I know it is not nice, but it is the best I could managed to do so far. My question is that using Linq to sql is not permitted using these two statements. The application throws an error, whereas this is ok :

```
triggers = triggers.Where(t => t.Name.Substring(t.Name.IndexOf(NameFirstSeparator) + 1, t.Name.IndexOf(NameSecondSeparator) - t.Name.IndexOf(NameFirstSeparator) - 1) == filter.Id.ToString());
```

I suspect that the function GetIdFromName should give something different than a string, but I really wonder what and how...

Thanks for your enlightenment,

Yoann

[EDIT] 
Update to what I understood so far:

I cannot do what i wanted, because in order to do so  I would need to do something of this kind :

```
static Expression<Func<Trigger,string,  bool>> IsId = (a,b) => a.name.Substring(a.name.IndexOf(NameFirstSeparator) + 1, a.name.IndexOf(NameSecondSeparator) - a.name.IndexOf(NameFirstSeparator) - 1)==b;
```

But this would not get into

```
triggers = triggers.Where(func<Trigger,bool>);
```

And I could manage to do it, but I would have to get all the results from my database to perform my test in memory.

Thanks a lot all, you made this get really clear to me!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ 2 SQL is converting your query into an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), and then translating that expression tree into SQL. Since your custom function doesn't have an SQL correlated function, it doesn't know how to translate it and throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I supected that, but the real things would be to know how to externalize these bits of code to "external" functions. This substring stuff here is pretty ugly and heavy and I would have liked to encapsulate it in a nice function. That should be possible because linq to sql is able to understand the raw format of it.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do what you're looking for. Expression trees only support a single expression, represented as a tree. To support methods in the manner you want, it would have to be able to handle blocks. For example, `x => { return x; }` cannot be compiled into an expression tree.

Comment: You can get around this limitation by calling `AsEnumerable()` before using your method. However, this has a big downside in that everything before the AsEnumerable call gets pulled into memory. Post `AsEnumerable()`, the query is LINQ to Objects with all the power it provides.