# ContainsAll Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ 2 SQL query does not work with a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770512/linq-2-sql-query-does-not-work-with-a-function-call)

I have the following problem, I need for Linq to SQL a ContainsAll method. But my code doesn't work...
Here is the code:
This is my ContainsAll Method:

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll, IEnumerable<T> items) {
    bool res = true;
    foreach (var item in items) {
        res &= coll.Contains(item);
    }
    return res;
}
```

This is the method where I call the query:

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers(int offset, int count, User currentUser) {
    log.Debug("get all users between " + offset + " and " + count);
    IEnumerable<Group> groups = currentUser.Groups;
    var data = from usr in ManagerUser
                where usr.Groups.Contains(groups)
                orderby usr.ID
                select usr;
    return data.Skip(offset).Take(count).ToList();
}
```

And this is the exception I receive:

```
System.NotSupportedException wurde nicht von Benutzercode behandelt.
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message='LINQ to Entities' erkennt die Methode 'Boolean Contains[Group](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Knerdprod.Manager.DatabaseConnection.Group], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Knerdprod.Manager.DatabaseConnection.Group])' nicht, und diese Methode kann nicht in einen Speicherausdruck übersetzt werden.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
       bei System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       bei System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
       bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       bei Knerdprod.Manager.DatabaseConnection.DatabaseModelEntities.GetAllUsers(Int32 offset, Int32 count, User currentUser) in c:\Users\Kirk\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Azure\Video und Statsmanager\DatabaseConnection\UserModelEntities.cs:Zeile 272.
       bei Knerdprod.Manager.WebServiceDatabaseMapper.Connectors.UserConnector.GetUserList(Int32 offset, Int32 count, User user) in c:\Users\Kirk\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Azure\Video und Statsmanager\WebServiceDatabaseMapper\Connectors\UserConnector.cs:Zeile 57.
       bei UserRestService.UserManagementService.GetUserList(String accesstoken, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in c:\Users\Kirk\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Azure\Video und Statsmanager\RestServices\User\UserManagementService.svc.cs:Zeile 119.
       bei UserRestService.UserManagementService.GetUserListJson(String accesstoken, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in c:\Users\Kirk\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Azure\Video und Statsmanager\RestServices\User\UserManagementService.svc.cs:Zeile 206.
       bei SyncInvokeGetUserListJson(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
       bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
       bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
  InnerException:
```

Has anyone an idea?

Lg Knerd

Comment: Thanks to SWeko for editing the code :)

Comment: Good question, is it possible to give an english stacktrace in an german VS?

Comment: There is an error on SequenceEqual and you give the code of a Contains method...

Comment: Yes, I need a method that gives a containsall method. My try with the ContainsAll method fails. So I tried SequenceEqual, which fails with the same exception.

Comment: I edited the code a little bit.